# Установка пакета через easy_install

Tags: python

Пытаюсь установить пакет не в стандартную директорию Python, а в свою собственную,
вот таким вот образом:

```
easy_install --install-dir D:\...\PythonLib requests[security]
```

выдается сообщение типа:

```
TEST FAILED: D:\...\PythonLib does NOT support .pth files
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

D:\...\PythonLib

and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

'c:\\JYTHON~1.0\\bin'

Here are some of your options for correcting the problem:

* You can choose a different installation directory, i.e., one that is
  on PYTHONPATH or supports .pth files

* You can add the installation directory to the PYTHONPATH environment
  variable.  (It must then also be on PYTHONPATH whenever you run
  Python and want to use the package(s) you are installing.)

* You can set up the installation directory to support ".pth" files by
  using one of the approaches described here:

https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#custom-installation-     locations

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

Понимаю, что надо что то сделать с PYTHONPATH, но не могу ни как разобраться!

Answer (score 1):

для Windows 7 -
Панель управления / система / дополнительные параметры системы / кнопка "переменные среды"
в блоке "системные переменные" создать или исправить (если есть) PYTHONPATH
в которой указать путь к каталогу с библиотеками. Может быть можно указать несколько путей через точку с запятой.

Comment: Я это сделал не помогает

Comment: запустить командную строку (cmd.exe), выполнить  - set | find "PYTHONPATH"